# NSMennuItems used in menubar right click menu appear grayed out and cant be clicked

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to use `NSTextField` as a `NSMenuItem`.

But it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
 class charPoolBoxForMenuItemInstance: NSTextField,NSTextFieldDelegate{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {super.init(coder: NSCoder.init())}
   override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
   if self.currentEditor()?.selectedRange != nil{UserDefaults.standard.set(self.stringValue, forKey: "charPoolBox")

    }
  }
}

var  charPoolBoxForMenuItem = charPoolBoxForMenuItemInstance.init(string: String.init())
```

Then I add it to my menu like so:

```
let charPoolMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
    charPoolMenuItem.title = "Character Pool"
    charPoolMenuItem.view = charPoolBoxForMenuItem
    charPoolBoxForMenuItem.placeholderString = "Character Pool"
    charPoolBoxForMenuItem.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: 400, height: 22)
    menuBarMenu.addItem(charPoolMenuItem)
```

And here's how it looks greyed out:

[image]

update :

```
@objc func resetPoolChar(){charPoolBoxForMenuItem.stringValue = "abc"}


     let charPoolMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
    charPoolMenuItem.title = "Character Pool"
    charPoolMenuItem.view = charPoolBoxForMenuItem
    charPoolMenuItem.action = #selector(resetPoolChar)
    charPoolBoxForMenuItem.placeholderString = "Character Pool"
    charPoolBoxForMenuItem.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: 400,          height: 22)
```

Comment: A menu item must have an action to be enabled implicitly.

Comment: even when i do that it changes nothing still grayed out, will work when im runing it trough xcode but as soon as i close the menu its grayed out the next time i open the menu

Comment: `UITextField` and maxOS? Right click in a menu bar? Is the menu item or the text field grayed out? Please edit the title and question.

Comment: no someone edited my question and changed it to utextfield

Comment: @papi_douchy Show your code for the action. How are you connecting the menu item to the action? Writing an action by itself isn't enough. A menu item has to be connected to an action for the menu item to be enabled.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk i updated my question to show u how i got it connected to the action

Answer (score 0):

You also need the target for the action:

```
   charPoolMenuItem.action = #selector(resetPoolChar)
   charPoolMenuItem.target = self
```